# Create field called "Year" in MonetDB

Tags: reserved-words, monetdb

How do I create a field with a reserved word as the name in MonetDB?

In MySQL I would just surround the field name with backticks, but this doesn't work in MonetDB. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in MonetDB, double quotes are used for identifiers.

```
CREATE TABLE test ("year" integer);
```